# Django form edit loads no values on first attempt or old values unless refreshed

Tags: django

I am working on a Django site that lets users create, edit and delete business profiles. So far my create and delete work perfectly.

The edit page fails a lot the first time i open it. Subsequently, it loads previous or old values unless refreshed.
I have a homepage that captures the selected checkbox id and sends an edit or delete view depending on button clicked. It also has a create button.
How do i fix this?

```
def eventedit(request):
global mybiz_ids
a = MyEvent.objects.get(id = int(mybiz_ids))
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyEventForm(request.POST, instance=a)
    #form = MyEventForm(instance=a)
    if form.is_valid():
        model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
        model_instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/bizprofile/success/') 

else:
    form = MyEventForm(instance = a)      
return render_to_response('bizprofile/editbizprofile.html', {'form': form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))




def managehome(request):
global biz_num, deletebiz_ids, mybiz_ids
if 'add_button' in request.POST:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/bizprofile/addbizevent/')
elif 'delete_button' in request.POST:
    deletebiz_ids = request.POST.get('recommendations') 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/bizprofile/deletebizprofile/')  
elif 'edit_button' and 'recommendations' in request.POST:
    mybiz_ids = request.POST.get('recommendations') ### only for one item
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/bizprofile/eventedit/') 
else:
    pass

biz_num= request.GET.get('biz_num')
all_entries = MyEvent.objects.filter(belongsto = biz_num)
if all_entries.exists():
    all_entries = all_entries
else:
    all_entries = ["Nothing here"]
return render_to_response('bizprofile/managehome.html', {'all_entries': all_entries}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is a section of my error. I reloaded the page and the error went away.

```
DoesNotExist at /bizprofile/eventedit/
MyEvent matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.simufone.com/bizprofile/eventedit/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
MyEvent matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using globals to pass values around in a web app. You must never, ever, ever do this. Since it is shared by the whole process, any previous request - from any user - would set the value.

If you need a piece of data in the view, you should pass it in the URL, or the POST data, or in the session.

Comment: So the problem then is with the globals? I will work on fixing that.

Comment: Upon further improvements i have realized that i need to send the id on the redirect view.  I have these two to work on but without much progress.  return HttpResponseRedirect('/bizprofile/eventedit/', args=(the_id,)) or
        return eventedit(request, the_id)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: How to properly add an argument or variable to a HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: All a redirect does is create a URL to redirect to. So you need to define a url pattern that accepts that argument.

Comment: I used sessions and it fixed the problem completely. Thanks.